# Python error when installing module to connect couchbase

Tags: python, couchbase, centos6

I'm using CentOS 6.3, Python 2.6 and Couchbase.
I downloaded couchbase1.0.0 package for Python from and follow the guide from this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchbase

But, when I run the build_ext command, I got this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcouchbase
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried to use *python setup.py install* command, I got the error above, too.
I changed into couchbase1.0.0 directory before running commands.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the packages described in the second, third, and fourth  bullet points installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed them all.

Answer (score 0):

Linker is missing couchbase library, did you install couchbase package and all -devel packages for it ? by packages I mean system packages, not python packages.

Comment: Yes, I did installed -devel packages.

Comment: Does `ldconfig  -p | grep couch` find anything ?

Comment: Yes, Dārayavahuš tdi

libcouchbase_libevent.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcouchbase_libevent.so
        libcouchbase.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libcouchbase.so.2